# How do I convert a 4-point Likert scale to a percentage?

Tags: likert

I have a number of survey results on a 4-point Likert scale e.g.

Very satisfied – 67%
Somewhat satisfied – 18%
Somewhat dissatisfied – 7%
Very dissatisfied – 8%

I wish to convert these results into a percentage score reflecting the overall level of satisfaction.

Please note: I am not concerned with whether this SHOULD be done or whether it will provide an accurate measure of the responses. I only wish to know HOW to perform this calculation.

Comment: You have only 4 numbers, I would just report them all, perhaps as a stacked bar. If you really want to use a single number, how about one of the following: (1) Two-thirds of the respondents were very satisfied; (2) $85\%$ of the respondents were satisfied. Since the distance between "somewhat" and "very" is not well-defined, I don't think you can meaningfully convert the ordinal scale to a numerical one.

Answer (score 1):

Many options

- Report percentages as they are: e.g. just as a table or graphically e.g. as a stacked barchart (pro: it is already a percentage, easy to do, no loss of information, con: with many categories a bit messy - perhaps that's why you seem to look for a single number)
- Take a cut-off: % that are at least "somewhat satisfied" (pro: easy and reasonably interpretable, con: loss of information by dichotomizing)
- Assign a score: e.g. 0 to 100 and form average of some form (pro: easy, con: hard to interpret/many choices - Is even spacing from 0 to 100 sensible? Is an average meaningful? Is the difference from 0 to 25 really the same as from 50 to 75?)
- Item response theory: anchor to some instrument (e.g. subsequent renewed business/use of service) and/or look at test-retest scores, then bring to a 0 to 100 scale (e.g. inv_logit function 100), if you must (pro: clear basis for linking it to something meaningful, reasonably solid theoretical basis that tries to get to an underlying concept, con: the most work, not much you can do in this direction, if you just have a single score on a single occasion for each person)
- There's probably quite a few more options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a score, it's possible, but will heavily depend on what do you quantitatively know about human psychology.

Assuming:

0) Wanton abuse of Bayes' Theorem (that's a given with me)

1) All four options are equally likely if chosen blindly (why wouldn't they be?)

2) The four categories match all four recognized clusters of people (glad, mad, and mediocre leaning towards either of the other two) in the model.

3) Some people are negativistic, some are optimistic - i.e. some people who are only mildly aggrieved give very dissatisfied scores, some people have some minor qualms but still give full score.

4) The distribution of attitudes is Gaussian, i.e. roughly the same amount of optimism and pessimism around the mean attitude.

5) The responses are independent, i.e. you're controlling for peer pressure and the like.

6) That 'true' Very and Somewhat Satisfied responses both count as Satisfied for your purposes.

7) The contentious part - marginal distributions. If you assume that out of all VSes, **one out of four** people gives a Somewhat Satisfied score because they had a bad day at work, and likewise **one out of four** VDs downplays it as just Somewhat Dissatisfied, and both **Somewhats** have **one pessimist and one optimist per 4 respondents**, this gives the following score:

$p(H|A,B,C,D) = p(H|A)p(A) + p(H|B)p(B) + p(H|C)p(C) + p(H|D)p(D)$

therefore given the marginals assumed:

$p(H|A,B,C,D) = 1*p(A) + 0.75*p(B) + 0.25*p(C)$

or, to substitute only the other variable:

$p(H|A,B,C,D) = p(H|A)*0.67 + p(H|B)*0.18 + p(H|C)*0.07 + p(H|D)*0.08$

plugging in both:

$p(H|A,B,C,D) = (1*0.67) + (0.75*0.18) + (0.25*0.07) + (0*0.08)$

$p(H|A,B,C,D) = 0.8225 $

**== 82.25%**

Where `H` is the latent Happiness variable and A-D are Very Satisfied -> Very Dissatisfied

Again, this is heavily dependent on the assumptions, particularly (7). To get proper values, you'd need to work based off some proper studies to know how real people act in these kinds of polls - aside from the variance around the true satisfaction, there might be some skew towards positive, negative or neutral attitudes. It's fairly simple to adapt this function to account for it, but you need the data.